# HTML.Raw is undefined in Meteor+Blaze+React app after meteor/npm update

Tags: meteor

My app uses the latest Meteor 1.4.1.1 with React for UI and use Blaze only for accounts-ui. It ran fine until I 'meteor update' and 'npm update' yesterday. Now the app show blank page because of the exception (`TypeError: HTML.Raw is not a function`) in `template.main.js` (below) which Blaze compiled from the simple `main.html` that provide the root for React.

```
Template.body.addContent((function() {
  var view = this;
  return HTML.Raw('<div id="app-root"></div>');
}));
Meteor.startup(Template.body.renderToDocument);
```

When I looked at the HTML object in console:-

[image: Checking the HTML.Raw in console]

I'm new to Meteor and have no idea what's happening. I guess the Blaze's global `HTML` object must have the `.raw` method for use here. But why it is missing?